# BottomNavigationView covering up fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation

When creating a new app in Android Studio, using the `Bottom Navigation Activity`, I've found that having things in the bottom of the fragment will not be shown, because the `BottomNavigationView` is hiding it. For example, I added a button to the `fragment_home.xml` file, and constrained it to the bottom of the fragment.

I've tried setting the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the `fragment` to both `match_parent` and `wrap_content` but neither changed anything. I fiddled with constraints for both the `BottomNavigationView` and the `fragment`, but that also didn't change anything. Any help would be appreciated.

So here's the activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's the fragment_home.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you launch android studio and create a new app using the bottom navigation activity example, and replace these two xml files, you'll see the issue I'm having.

Comment: Include your layout XML.

Comment: Please share you xml code snnipet to help you

Comment: please share your code along with the question, so that someone can try to help.

Comment: Please share your xml snippet of code to help you.

Comment: please add your xml in question

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added the xml with a brief explanation of how to set up the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution I've found is that I could add `android:paddingBottom="56dp"` to the fragment_home.xml file:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">
...
```

However that doesn't really answer what I want to know - which is why the `fragment` view doesn't respect the constraints that I give it..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the solution that worked for me was changing the layout height in the activity_main.xml file:

From : android:layout_height="match_parent" ,

To : android:layout_height="0dp".

Once you set constraints for the fragment height, if you leave it on 'match parent' and not set to "0", it will ignore the constraints you set.

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally don't waste your time and copy this:

```
android:paddingBottom="56dp"
```

On your root tag like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="56dp"
tools:context=".RouteFragment">
```